# Icons not loading properly when I change my module, complaining about Cross origin requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am playing with some tutorials I found online in order to lean Angular.

The tutorial came with a module defined like this:

```
.module('MyApp')
```

and if I tried to change the name into something else an error would appear saying that the module is not found, so I changed it to this:

```
.module('materialApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])
```

following the proper way of defining modules according to the docs.

After doing this though all my icons have disappeared. So icons that previously displayed correctly

```
<md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/more_vert.svg"></md-icon>
```

Now cannot be loaded complaining that:

*Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.*

Comment: How do you run your application ? It seems that the file:// protocol might be involved, which may happens if you serve your files directly.

Also, do you have some more code to share ? That would help.

Comment: Its a simple .html and .js file that I have locally. I am not sure what to share so [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbzNKy) is a test I made. If you click next to each list item you will trigger a popup, even though you cant see the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

or the other option is to run your 'app' from a server to allow for cross origin requests